# all partitions became dynamic due to startup repair utility

Tags: partitioning, windows-installation, diskpart

All my disk partitions including system reserved and c: have become dynamic, due to which I am unable to boot linux. I wish to make some primary partitions. Ubuntu cant help since pc wont boot it even from usb. I have tried using disk management utility but it wont delete c: and system reserved for obvious reasons. But what is surprising is that even if I try to delete those partitions at installation time using bootable win 7 usb, it wont permit me. solution suggested elsewhere is to use a dos dvd. Is there a better way?. Can I use the win 7 command line at install time to do this.? Does working through usb or dvd create a difference.? What commands should I get familiar with?

Comment: I would suggest a live Linux disk so you are able to format your storage device the correct way.  You have to be clear the reason it won't let you, it has to tell you the reason, so tell us that reason.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, the only safe way to convert from "dynamic disks" (aka a [Logical Disk Manager, or LDM,](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_Disk_Manager) setup) is to use a Windows tool such as [EaseUS Partition Master](http://www.partition-tool.com/personal.htm) or [Partition Wizard.](http://partitionwizard.com/) Note that I've never used either tool, and I may have misremembered one or both names, so check the product descriptions for the ability to convert an LDM disk to a conventional setup before using it.